# java regex string split by " not \"

Tags: java, regex

actually I need to write just a simple program in JAVA to convert MySQL INSERTS lines into CSV files (each mysql table equals one CSV file)

is the best solution to use regex in JAVA?

My main problem how to match correctly value like this:  'this is \'cool\'...' 
(how to ignore escaped ')

example:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('this is \'cool\'...' ,'some2');
INSERT INTO `table1` (`field1`,`field2`) VALUES ('this is \'cool\'...' ,'some2');
```

Thanks

Comment: Actaully, you can't ignore them, you need to convert them to non-escaped for writing you your CVS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your SQL statements are syntactically valid, you could use

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("'(?:\\\\.|[^'\\\\])*'");
```

to get a regex that matches all single-quoted strings, ignoring escaped characters inside them.

**Explanation** without all those extra backslashes:

```
'         # Match '
(?:       # Either match...
 \\.      # an escaped character
|         # or
 [^'\\]   # any character except ' or \
)*        # any number of times.
'         # Match '
```

Given the string

```
'this', 'is a \' valid', 'string\\', 'even \\\' with', 'escaped quotes.\\\''
```

this matches

```
'this'
'is a \' valid'
'string\\'
'even \\\' with'
'escaped quotes.\\\''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match on chars within non-escaped quotes by using this regex:

```
(?<!\\)'([^'])(?<!\\)`
```

This is using a negative look-behind to assert that the character before the quote is *not* a bask-slash.

In jave, you have to double-escape (once for the String, once for the regex), so it looks like:

```
String regex = "(?<!\\\\)'([^'])(?<!\\\\)`";
```

If you are working in linux, I would be using [`sed`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_sed.htm) to do all the work.

Comment: What do you do if the string ends in an escaped backslash (`'this is it! \\'`)?

Comment: What if the \\ is actually part of an escaped back-slash then an escaped-quote: 'this is it! \\\'). The regex approach will never replace a bullet-proof parser.

Comment: Unless you have to deal with comments (containing strings you don't want to match) in your input string, I think the regex approach is fine (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Four backslashes (two to represent a backslash) plus dot. "'(\\\\.|.)*'"

Answer (score 0):

Although regexes give you a very powerful mechanism to parse text, I think you might be better off with a non-regex parser. I think you code will be easier to write, easier to understand and have fewer bugs.

Something like:

- find "INSERT INTO"
- find table name
- find column names
- find "VALUES"
- find value set (loop this part)

Writing the regex to do all of the above, with optional column values and an optional number of value sets is non-trivial and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `\\\\`. In Java Strings `\\`is one `\`, because the backslash is used to do whitespace or control characters (`\n`,`\t`, ...). But in regex a backslash is also represented by '\'.